linux luks cryptsetup - fallocate or urandom
does it make a difference if i create an empty file with fallocate, run cryptsetup on it, and write into the file until the last free byte is gone or create a file with data from urandom and than run cryptsetup on it?

So basically you mean this?
# format it
cryptsetup luksFormat file.img

# open it
cryptsetup open file.img cryptfile

# write into it until the last free byte
cp /dev/urandom /dev/mapper/cryptfile

cryptsetup luksFormat wipes the entire header with random data. In case of LUKS 2, that's 16MiB of random data, even though only a fraction of that is actually used (roughly 300KB for header and first keyslot).
Overwriting /dev/mapper/cryptfile then fills the remaining file with random data (encrypted ciphertext). The resulting file is one that is random data start to end (except for the LUKS header which has magic bytes, readable ASCII/JSON strings, etc).
Does it make a difference if file.img was urandom or zero? Not in this case.
If you create the file from /dev/urandom, you can skip writing more random data to it. It's already random, there's no need to write it twice. If your intention was to create a file that is entirely random data, then using /dev/urandom to create it might make your intention clearer.

It might make a difference if you just don't trust /dev/urandom. Encrypted random data is better than just random data, right? Well, actually no. That would only be the case if the kernel's random algorithm sucked. If you don't trust /dev/urandom you have a problem in general, because that's where cryptsetup gets all its keys and random data from.
If you think it's possible to derive urandom internal state by watching lots of urandom output, then writing a file from urandom directly before luksFormat (and even just wiping the header with random data) might be a bad idea, since it could reveal the volume key.
However realistically that should just not be possible. Basically these concerns are too theoretical and far-fetched to be considered seriously in practice.

That leaves different use-cases. For example write zeroes instead of random data:
# write zeroes until the last free byte
cp /dev/zero /dev/mapper/cryptfile

For file.img this does not change much, encrypted zeroes still looks like random data.
However, /dev/mapper/cryptfile will appear as fully zero. This can be used to verify that the file was written correctly and in full. If you wrote zeroes (encrypted) and don't get zeroes back (decrypted) then something is wrong with your storage. You can detect media level corruption, fake USB sticks and the like with it, or just guarantee that a drive was wiped with random data properly.
Basically if you want decrypted data to look a certain way, you have to write it that way yourself.

There's also the case of using the device normally:
# we probably want a filesystem
mkfs /dev/mapper/cryptfile

Now it depends on whether or not you use cryptsetup with --allow-discards.
Most variants of mkfs discard all data. Once mounted, it might also happen at a later time with fstrim. That's one case where file.img throws away all that random data and it's back to zero. In that case there was not much point in using /dev/urandom to create it.
